# AWS: STS Assume Role not working for user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have created an AWS Policy with the below definition. I have assigned this to an IAM User so the user can get a temporary access. However, the user gets this error: "User xxxx is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on ...".

The AWS documentation says this is the only policy that is required.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Side-note: The above permissions mean that the user could assume _any_ IAM Role, including ones that might contain administrative-level permissions. Be very careful when granting such open permissions.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the IAM policy that allows the user to assume a role, You also need to add a `Trust Policy` to the role. The trust policy tells who can assume the role. I think you are missing the trust policy.

Hope this helps.

Reference:
[Assume an IAM Role Using the AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-assume-role-cli/)